# Getting timezone not found error while performing group by month in Laravel Carbon

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to run the following SQL query in Laravel Eloquent syntax (not correct yet so not shown here) to select the number of occurrences of `startdate` in a given range of dates:

```
SELECT  COUNT(startdate) as TotalCount 
FROM    Users
WHERE   startdate >= '2017-01-01' 
AND     startdate <= '2017-12-31'
AND     startdate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Month(startdate)
```

Now, I am aware that this might not be right. The `GroupBy` in particular is not correct. I also keep getting a "Timezone not found in Database" error. How do I correct the error and perform a correct query, so that the results are somewhat like the following:

```
January: 1
February: 3
March: 0
April: 9
....
```

**EDIT:** The erroneous PHP Code:

```
 $starters = User::select(DB::raw('Count(*), startdate'))
        ->groupBy(Carbon::parse('startdate')->format('m'))
        ->get();
```

Comment: Why do you say the GROUP BY is not correct? Also the error is a PHP error not a MySQL error, where's the corresponding PHP code?

Comment: Show your PHP code, since the error is coming from Carbon, not MySQL.

Comment: @apokryfos, please find changes in the edits. Thanks

Comment: You're asking Carbon to parse a date before you fire the query, that's not right. Use `groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(startdate)"))`

Comment: @apokryfos Cheers, works. Why does it give the tz error the other way round tho?

Comment: Because you're asking carbon to parse the string literal "startdate", it assumes it's a timezone and says, "wait that's not actually a timezone"

Comment: Okay, and in the answer, could you also explain how could I get a result like the one I wrote above, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `MONTHNAME` function as documented here... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname

For your query, it would be pretty simple to use.

```
SELECT  MONTHNAME(startdate) AS `month`, COUNT(*) AS `TotalCount`
FROM    Users
WHERE   startdate >= '2017-01-01' 
AND     startdate <= '2017-12-31'
AND     startdate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(startdate)
```

You almost always want to select whatever you are grouping by and the rest of the items you are selecting should be aggregates (things like count, sum, avg, etc...)

You just need to be careful here though because if you go back more than one year, it will start including results for the same month in both years because you are only grouping by the month.  If that's what you want, then obviously that's okay but it might be necessary to also add `YEAR(startdate)` in the select and group by of your query as well.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your answer my laravel query is: `User::select(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(startdate) as month,YEAR(startdate) as year, Count(*) as count'))
            ->whereIn($this->getCurrentYearDates())
            ->whereNotNull('startdate')
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTHNAME(startdate), YEAR(startdate)"))
            ->get();` I have a function in here that returns string literals of all dates of the current year.

Comment: As long as it's returning dates in the right format (Y-m-d), looks good.  You can also turn on the MySQL general log which will log all queries.  I like to `tail -f` it so I can see the queries being ran in real time just to make sure there were no mistakes in converting the query to the query builder.

Comment: At the moment it shows the months for which the count is more than 0. Would it be possible to show months where count is 0 as well?

Comment: That might be difficult to do just because you are trying to grab data which isn't there.  Your best bet would be to loop through the results you get back with PHP and if you find a missing month, add it in before sending it to your view.